# Multiple Lucene queries Wildcard Searches and Proximity matching

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene to auto complete words in a search engine(RTL language) the auto complete function invoked after insertion of 3 letters.

I'd like to have a proximity matching to the 3 letters query before invoking the Wildcard function.

For example I'd like to make a sub-string search to my db only for the first 3 letters for every entry, with a proximity matching to this comparison.

presumably I'm looking for digger but I'd also like to have doggy in my results, so if I've entered
**dig** (the first 3 letters in the search engine) with a proximity matching equals to 1, **digger** and **doggy** would surface.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IndexReader's `Terms` methods to enumerate terms in the index. You can then use a custom function to calculate the distance between these terms and the text you search. I'll use [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for demo.

```
var terms = indexReader.ClosestTerms(field, "dig")
                       .OrderBy(t => t.Item2)
                       .Take(10)
                       .ToArray();
```

---

```
public static class LuceneUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> ClosestTerms(this IndexReader reader, string field, string text)
    {
        return reader.TermsStartingWith(field, text[0].ToString())
                     .Select(x => new Tuple<string, int>(x, LevenshteinDistance(x, text)));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> TermsStartingWith(this IndexReader reader, string field, string text)
    {
        using (var tEnum = reader.Terms(new Term(field, text)))
        {
            do
            {
                var term = tEnum.Term;
                if (term == null) yield break;
                if (term.Field != field) yield break;
                if (!term.Text.StartsWith(text)) yield break;
                yield return term.Text;
            } while (tEnum.Next());
        }
    }

    //http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein
    public static int LevenshteinDistance(string s, string t)
    {
        int n = s.Length;
        int m = t.Length;
        int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

        // Step 1
        if (n == 0) return m;

        if (m == 0) return n;


        // Step 2
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++) { }

        for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++) { }

        // Step 3
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            //Step 4
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
            {
                // Step 5
                int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                // Step 6
                d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                    Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                    d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
            }
        }
        // Step 7
        return d[n, m];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can try doing it, you will just need to add search criteria of Wildcard after Proximity search.

Have you read this?
http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-query-syntax.html

Also take a look at 
[Lucene proximity search with boundaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378658/lucene-proximity-search-with-boundaries)

Comment: Yes, I've looked into these sites. 
I've edited my question to clarify my self, please check it out.