# Lucene Full Text search with promixity anchor

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search, proximity

I am trying to modify my lucene application in order to make full text searches from HTML files but also I would like to obtain the closest anchor .

As an example if I have this HTML code:

```
.......
<a name="1"></a>
<p style="font-size:12pt;text-align: justify;text-indent:30px;">
    closest anchor i would like to find.
</p>
.......
<a name="2"></a>
<p style="font-size:12pt;text-align: justify;text-indent:30px;">
    testing full text search.
</p>
.......
```

If I search the string "full text search" I would like to obtain the anchor with name 2 in order to make the position in the html.

I've heard that this is possible with Solr. Currently I am not using it because I use Hibernate Search as a core library with Lucene.

So, any ideas?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I've found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378658/lucene-proximity-search-with-boundaries

Comment: any examples on this?